# Vue.js, How to check v-if directive with the results of an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am showing to users, a web app which has links to another website. Depending on which link the user clicks on, it will take them to another page or stay on the same page.

My current implementation approach is to have a "v-if" directive that checks the results of an async function, but the value of the function always returns "Promise pending" and not the actual value.

I am trying to do something like

```
<router-link v-else-if="checkValue(origin.link)" target="_blank" :to= "origin/link" >
                          <span @click="checkValue(origin.link)">
                            {{ origin.value }} 
                          </span>
                        </router-link>
```

the issue here is that "checkValue" in the v-if is an promise, so it never gets the true or false value, in the v-if.

I cannot store the data of this call in an data variable because there is millions and millions of records, and I can't store all of them. "checkValue" is an asynchronous function like so

```
async checkValue(link: string) {
      const val = await axios.get('service/${link}')
            if(val) {
               return true
            } else {
               return false
            }
```

Is there a way in the v-if directive, that I can check the return of this asynchronous function? Or Is there another approach I can do to solve this? thank you

Answer (score 1):

you need not store the data of this call in an data variable,you can modify your code like this.

```
    <router-link v-else-if="hasValue" target="_blank" :to= "origin/link" >
        <span @click="checkValue(origin.link)">
             {{ origin.value }} 
        </span>
    </router-link>

   <script>
      export default {
           data: function {
              return {
                hasValue: false
              }
           }
           created: function() {
              axios.get('service/${link}').then(c => {
                   this.hasValue = !!c
              })
            
          }
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: The issue with this, Is I am trying to do an API call on dynamic links that comes from a database, I can't make the API call in the created, It needs to fetch the data first for what links to make an API call with.

Comment: where is the variable origin obtained?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use the v-if (or v-show) directive with a variable. I haven't tested the snippet below, but something like this should work:

```
try{
  let response = await axios.get('service/${link}')
      this.useThisVariableInVIF = true // or response.data.message;
  }catch(error) {
      this.useThisVariableInVIF = false;
      console.log(error);
    };
}
```

Then just `v-else-if="useThisVariableInVIF"`